# How to create a File using json data from postman in python

Tags: python, json, post, postman

```
from aiohttp import web
import os
import json
```

i want to create a file with input parameters in post request

server async http python

get request

```
async def handle(request):
    path = "C://Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros"
    dir_list = os.listdir(path)
    text = str(dir_list)
    return web.Response(text=text)
```

post request for creating a json file

```
async def handler(requests):
    def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
        filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
        with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)
            fp.write(data)
        writeToJSONFile("C:/Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros", "data1", "book")
app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.post('/', handler)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What JSON file do you means? I don't see any JSON file in your question.

Comment: basically i need a post request that generate a file when a put some parameters like ( { "key" : "123456789", "length" : 100000, "fileName" : "REI" } ) in the raw json in postman with a python server

Comment: async def handler(requests):
    def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
        filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
        with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)
            fp.write(data)
        writeToJSONFile("C:/Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros", "data1", "book")
app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.post('/', handler)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)

Comment: why do you put `def writeToJSONFile()` inside `async def handler()`? This makes code unreadable. And you have wrong indentations in function so it can makes problem.

Comment: im a beginner >(

Comment: you have wrong indentation and you have  `writeToJSONFile("C...")` inside `def writeToJSONFile()` so it can't execute it. If you would define `def writeToJSONFile()` outside `async def handler()` then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: or you could put all code directly in `async def handler()` without creating function `def writeToJSONFile()`. BTW: names `hande` and `handler` are very similar it can make mess in code when you make mistake in name. More readable could be `get()` and `post()` or `get_list()` and `post_data()`

Comment: BTW: code `json.dump(data, fp)` is writing data to file, you don't need `fp.write(data)`

Comment: BTW: If you will append data to existing file using `open(..., 'a')` then you create broken file. You have to read old content to python, add new value in python, aand write all again to file.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentation and you have `writeToJSONFile("C...")` inside `def writeToJSONFile()` so it can't execute it.

```
async def handler(requests):
    def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
        filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
        with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)

    #<-- at the same column as `def`
    writeToJSONFile("C:/Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros", "data1", "book")
```

If you would define `def writeToJSONFile()` outside async `def handler()` then you wouldn't have this problem.

```
def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt =  path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)

async def handler(requests):
    writeToJSONFile("C:/Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros", "data1", "book")
```

---

**BTW:**

`json.dump(data, fp)` writes data to file, you don't need `fp.write(data)` - besides `fp.write()` writes as normal text, not JSON data.

You would have to use `dumps` instead of `dump` - `fp.write(json.dumps(data))`

---

There is other problem - using `open(..., 'a')` you create wrong JSON file. You can't use this to append new data to existing file. You have to read all data to Python, add value in Python, and write all data again to file (and remove previous content).

---

Full working code with other changes

```
import os
import json
from aiohttp import web

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants
                     # PEP8: all constants before functions
                     
#PATH = "C:/Users/berto/Desktop/MEGSI - ESI 1/ITI/Servidor/Ficheiros"
PATH = '.'

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables
                     # PEP8: all functions before main code

def write_to_json_file(path, filename, data):
    file_path_name_with_ext = os.path.join(PATH, filename+'.json')
    print('path:', file_path_name_with_ext)
    
    with open(file_path_name_with_ext, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
    
async def get_handler(request):
    dir_list = sorted(os.listdir(PATH))
    
    #text = str(dir_list)
    #text = json.dumps(dir_list)
    text = '\n'.join(dir_list)
    
    return web.Response(text=text)   # as text

    #text = '<br>'.join(dir_list)
    #return web.Response(text=text, content_type='text/html')  # as HTML

    #text = json.dumps(dir_list)
    #return web.Response(text=text, content_type='application/json')   # as JSON

    #return web.json_response(dir_list)   # as JSON

async def post_handler(request):
    write_to_json_file(PATH, "data1", "book")
    
    return web.Response(text='OK')

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.get('/', get_handler),
        web.post('/', post_handler)
    ])
    web.run_app(app)
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

To test `POST` you can also use popular shell command [curl](https://curl.se/) (if you have installed)

```
curl --request POST http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

or popular Python module `requests` (if you have installed)

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8080')

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

or you can use `aiohttp`

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('http://0.0.0.0:8080') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

asyncio.run(main())
```